# Embedded UICollectionView inside ContainerView - on rotate problems

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I went through all similar StackOverflow questions but didn't found the solution.

I have:

- Main ViewController with Container View (all AutoLayouted without any problems)
- Inside Container View is CollectionViewController (Horizontal layout)
- Now, cell sizes are dynamically set (as seen from the picture) based on view.frame.height
- Everything is OK untill I rotate device. Although the cell sizes **are correctly resized and drawn** I get console error:

"***the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.***"

At the same time I always get two (2) warnings (probably for 2 collection view cells before rotation):

"***Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.***"

I've tried everything...Any ideas?

[image: Debug error]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probleme in my app.
I fixed this by recreating the flow layout on each rotation.

Example code :

```
/**
 * Update the layout based on screen size
 *
 * @param CGSize
 * @return void
 */
- (void)updateLayoutBasedOnSize:(CGSize)size {

    // Configure layout
    CGSize offersSize;

    // iPad Layout
    if ([UIDevice isIPad]) {
        if (size.width > size.height) {
            // 4 cols
            offersSize = CGSizeMake((size.width / 4) - 15.0f,
                                    (((size.width / 4) / 3) * 2) - 20.0f);
        } else {
            // 2 cols
            offersSize = CGSizeMake((size.width / 2) - 15.0f,
                                    (((size.width / 2) / 3) * 2) - 20.0f);
        }

    // iPhone layout
    } else {
        if (size.width > size.height) {
            // 2 cols
            offersSize = CGSizeMake((size.width / 2) - 15.0f,
                                    (((size.width / 2) / 3) * 2) - 20.0f);
        } else {
            // 1 col
            offersSize = CGSizeMake(size.width - 20.0f,
                                    ((size.width / 3) * 2) - 20.0f);
        }
    }

    offersSize.height += 30.0f;

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:offersSize];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    [_collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

}
```

And I call this method on each interface rotation with the collectionView size as parameter.

PS : I use some custom methods like `[UIDevice isIPad]` but it doesn't matter in the answer.

Comment: Is there any one-liner solution? I wouldn't like to make custom hacks for this to work :).

Comment: No sorry... All can't be done with one line. the minimum to update your layout to fit is the part with the flowLayout. ContainerView is still a bit buggy

Comment: Ok I'll try it. Anyways it seems to me there should be more elegant solution, because problem happens only when rotating from portrait -> landscape. There aren't any problems when App starts in portrait mode. Really weird.